# How can I visualize data to show performance and variation in performance

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization, presentation

I wanted to know the how I could plot what I'm seeing in my data.

For context, I have the numerical performance score each individual student has received in 9 different subjects (my snapshot only includes 4 of these). I have this data for around 50 students. One fact that's of interest to me, is whether there is between subject variation for a student in their performance. For example, I want to know if students are either consistently high or low performers across all subjects or if there is some variation in their performance.

How could I plot this?

```
student_id  Math_score  English_score  Social_studies_score  Chemistry_score
42             20            15              16                    12
41             23            23              14                    18
40             6             12              20                    23
32             18             9              23                    22
34             15            21              23                    21
45             10             8              22                    18
39             20            12              18                     6
10             23            19              17                    14
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, just plotting the raw data, but clarifying things by sorting the students by average score.

First I reshape the data long using `tidyr::pivot_longer`, which puts the data into a format that works better with ggplot2. Then I take the step of changing the student id into an ordered factor in order of mean score across all subjects.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-student_id) %>%
  mutate(student_id = student_id %>% as.factor %>% 
           fct_reorder(value, mean) %>% fct_rev) 

ggplot(df_long, aes(student_id, value, color = name)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
                student_id = c(42L, 41L, 40L, 32L, 34L, 45L, 39L, 10L),
                Math_score = c(20L, 23L, 6L, 18L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 23L),
             English_score = c(15L, 23L, 12L, 9L, 21L, 8L, 12L, 19L),
      Social_studies_score = c(16L, 14L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 18L, 17L),
           Chemistry_score = c(12L, 18L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 6L, 14L)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use `geom_boxplot` to show the median and range of scores across subjects by student.

By adding a `geom_point` layer, you could additionally show the subject scores.

To scale it up to 500 students, I've grouped the students in to 4 quartiles based on their mean scores using `cut_interval`. You could choose any number of groups.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

# Sample data
df <- tibble(
  student_id = 1:500,
  Math_score = rnorm(500, 23, 1.2),
  English_score = rnorm(500, 24, 1.3),
  Social_studies_score = rnorm(500, 22, 1.4),
  Chemistry_score = rnorm(500, 20, 1.1)
)

# Summarise and plot
df |> 
  pivot_longer(-student_id, values_to = "score", names_to = "subject") |> 
  group_by(student_id) |> 
  mutate(mean_score = mean(score)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(quartile = cut_interval(mean_score, n = 4, 
                                 labels = c("Bottom Quartile", "Lower Quartile", 
                                            "Upper Quartile", "Top Quartile")),
         quartile = fct_reorder(quartile, mean_score)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(quartile, score, group = quartile)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = subject), width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Score", colour = "Subject",
       title = glue("Scores for {nrow(df)} Students")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! For few student Ids this would be great but in case I have large number of observations (n=500) then is there any way I could graphically present this information?

Comment: @Kiara I've adjusted the plot to scale up to 500 students.

Answer (score 0):

One option that will scale well to more subjects and students is a waffle-style plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(df, -1) %>%
  mutate(Student = factor(student_id),
         Subject = sub(' score', '', gsub('_', ' ', name))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Student, Subject, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(size = 3, color = 'white') +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(fill = 'Score') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_void(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(),
        axis.title = element_text(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10),
                                    size = 20),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]

Expanding to 50 students and 10 subjects might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this is a really nice representation - I think if i were to use this approach on around 500 observations, i think this plot could get a lot more convoluted? in that case, is there any way I could graphically present this information?

Comment: @Kiara see my update which shows how it would look with 500 observations (50 students and 10 subjects) - obviously the plot is a bit squished here, but looks good at full screen size.